# Why smoothScrollTo not work immediately after adding sibling RelativeLayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-relativelayout

I have parent **RelativeLayout (RL)** inside **ScrollView (SV)**. In parent RL I have one child also RL. I want to add another child RL to parent RL and scroll down on screen height

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.width,
   this.height);
lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, first_child.getId());
new_layout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
rl.addView(new_layout);
int current_pos = sv.getScrollY();
sv.smoothScrollTo(0,current_pos + this.height);
```

The new child RL successfully added to parent but **smootScrollTo** method dose not working correctly. It's like **addView()** method is work asynchronously, and when method **smoothScrollTo** is calling, parent RL yet not contain new child RL.

How I can add new child RL in parent and immediately scroll down screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.width,
       this.height);
    lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, first_child.getId());
    new_layout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    rl.addView(new_layout);
    int height = this.height;
        sv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int current_pos = sv.getScrollY();
                    sv.smoothScrollTo(0,current_pos + height);
                }
            });
```

Comment: So, if method post() add message to queue then addView is async method? How to send data to Runnable object? In my case I need access to sv inside run() method? Override calss Runnable?

Comment: Not quite understand the question. What exactly does not work?

Comment: How to get access to sv or any other variable, inside run() method?

Comment: sv must be final only. As I understand you you can not determine this.height = 0. If you tell me what is meant by "this", maybe I can help you

Comment: Ok, it's works. But why it is not work in imperative style without creating new Runnable object? i.e. why this code is not work?    `rl.addView(new_layout);
int current_pos = sv.getScrollY();
sv.smoothScrollTo(0,current_pos + this.height);`

Comment: You are trying to scroll while your Activity is not yet uploaded. Method post may be delayed, while Activities already created. I think so

Comment: Is no exists another way to wait until new child layout fully loaded without using Runnable object and ScrollView.post() method?

Answer (score 2):

**Following code will work:**

```
            final int scrollposition = Math.round(hr/24.0f * 1440f);

            final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.graphScrollView);
            //sv.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollposition);

            sv.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sv.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollposition);
                }
            });
```

**Reason:**
It will wait for the scrollview to be posted before running the underlying code.